# How can I put a small bit of a string in a another string?

Tags: c++

I have a Question. I want to copy something from a string. I have this:

```
    string buffer = "
{"clientToken":"clientToken","accessToken":"abdjuhsdhjsksdnasfldafgkuadbkghubdfhlujgbdfhulgdfbhugfdbgujhlfdanhjgkhdfanhnjkgbafdhkugbadcjgfdabhgfdabgjhdfabkhgfdbghujfdabghkjfdabghujfadbgfdjhaugbafdhjujgjbfuhkgbf 
dhugdbfauhgbfaluhgbdafilgbdfhgfdigujladbijfbghdufjbvgfbhgadbfgbdfjgfbgjfdbjflbgjedfbgauiadfbuigbuifgdabhf 
juhgbdaihjfhgbdiuflghbdfiugbfdugbbbbb","selectedProfile": 
{"name":"secret","id":"secret"},"availableProfiles":[{"name":"secret","id":"nothing"}]}";
    string token;
```

and i want to put the accestoken (the long gibberish) into the string token(the rest is not needed only the accesstoken). Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is it always 4th quoted string? You could use `std::string::find` to find the 7th and 8th `"` characters and then you're good to go.

Comment: If you want to parse JSON in general, get hold of a library for that.

Comment: you have to escape the quotes. `buffer` is syntax errors

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to do it, but the most simple is to locate `"accessToken"` with `std::string::find()`, then located leading and ending `"` of the token value itself, and then use `std::string::substr()` to extract a necessary piece. But in general, you better use some json parsing library, like https://github.com/nlohmann/json